# How do I share a JIRA dashboard with one customer?

Tags: jira

I've set up a dashboard for one of our customers and I'm trying to find the best way to share it with them. The customer should have an account in the system, I do not want the dashboard to be publicly visible and I do not want the customer to have access to anything other than the dashboard.

I have created an account for them in the system, but I cannot work out how to configure the groups, roles and permissions appropriately. Can anyone provide some guidance here?

Answer (score 1):

Define a JIRA group named customerA

Add your customer's userid to the group

Create the dashboard

Share the dashboard with the group

Share the dashboard with users of a project, or a group such as mycompany-staff. Not jira-users though since everyone will be in that group.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have shared the dashboard. However, most of the widgets do not work due to the user being locked out of everything. Do you know if there is any way to share a filter without the user actually having full access to the project?